# Django Haystack - Indexing single field

Tags: python, django, search, django-haystack

I am using Django [Haystack](http://haystacksearch.org) for search.

I **only** want to target the `title` field of my model when searching for results.

At present however, it returns results if the search term is in any of the fields in my model.

For example: searching *xyz* gives results where *xyz* is in the `bio` field.

This should not happen, I only want to return results where *xyz* is in the `title` field. Totally ignoring all other fields other than `Artist.title` for searching on.

`artists/models.py` :

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    strapline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_file_path, storage=s3, max_length=500)
    bio = models.TextField()
```

`artists/search_indexes.py`

```
from haystack import indexes
from app.artists.models import Artist

class ArtistIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True, model_attr='title')

    def get_model(self):
        return Artist
```

I guess thinking of it like a SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM artists WHERE title LIKE '%{search_term}%'
```

**UPDATE**

Following suggestion to remove use_template=True, my search_indexes.py now looks like:

```
from haystack import indexes
from app.artists.models import Artist


class ArtistIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, model_attr='title')
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')

    def get_model(self):
        return Artist
```

But I am having the same problem. (Have tried python manage.py rebuild_index)

This is my Haystack settings if that makes any difference:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.simple_backend.SimpleEngine',
    },
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`model_attr` and  `use_template` don't work together. In this case, as you're querying for a single model attribute there's no need to use a template. Templates in search indexes are purely meant to group data.

Thus, you end up with:

```
class ArtistIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, model_attr='title')

    def get_model(self):
        return Artist
```

Comment: Thank you, I've added an update to my question above as this doesn't seem to have resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any other use case for your index (ie searches that should match terms elsewhere) you just have to not `use_template` at all (set the `use_template` param to `False` and just ditch your search template) and you'll be done. FWIW note that when passing `True` for `use_template` the `model_attr` param is ignored. Also, you may not have a use for a full text search engine then, you could possibly just use Django's standard QuerySet lookup API, ie `Artist.objects.filter(title__icontains=searchterm)`.

Else - if you still need a 'full' document index for other searches and only want to restrict this one search to the `title` you can as well add another `index.CharField` (with `document=False, model_attr='title'`) for the title and only search on this field. How to do so is fully documented in Haystack's SearchQuerySet API doc.

Comment: Thank you, I've added an update to my question above as this doesn't seem to have resolved my problem.

Comment: @kieran: you have to rebuild your whole index each time you change your index definitions. Also, did you read the big red warning about the SimpleEngine backend ? https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#simple

Comment: yep have been doing that. This will be moved to Solr when ready for production

Comment: @kieran : if you don't want to use Solr for dev the best fallback is Whoosh - but as soon as you need anything but the most basic features Haystack ends up being a somewhat leaky abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs

Additionally, we’re providing `use_template=True` on the text field. This allows us to use a data template (rather than error prone concatenation) to build the document the search engine will use in searching. You’ll need to create a new template inside your template directory called `search/indexes/myapp/note_text.txt` and place the following inside:

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.user.get_full_name }}
{{ object.body }}
```

So I guess in this template you can declare which fields should be indexed/ searched upon

Other way is to override the `def prepare(self, object)` of Index class and explicitly define fields that need to be indexed/ searched upon.
OR just use `model_attr`

Comment: Thank you, I've added an update to my question above as this doesn't seem to have resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your *search_indexes.py* file is written wrong. It should be like:-

```
from haystack import indexes
from app.artists.models import Artist

class ArtistIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title= indexes.CharField(model_attr='title',null=True)

def get_model(self):
    return Artist

def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

Then you have to create a template in your app. The directory structure would be like:

> templates/search/indexes/artists/artist_text.txt

and add the following code to the artist_text.txt file:

```
{{ object.title }}
```

Now do **python manage.py rebuild_index.**

Now It will return result only for title.